# Working with different implementations of cp across different environments

Tags: linux, macos, bash, script, shell-script

So I figured GNU's cp is different than OSX's (BSD).

While OSX copies the contents of a directory that ends with a slash, or the directory itself without the slash, GNU/Linux just treats `somedir` and `somedir/` the same (i.e. copies the directory).

This is annoying because now one of my shell scripts looks like this:

```
# copy the contents of somedir in $path
if [ "$(uname -s)" = "Darwin" ] ; then
  cp -R somedir/ $path
else
  cp -R --no-target-directory somedir $path
fi
```

It works, but it feels a bit clunky to me.

So is there a better way? Maybe some command that just works universally across different OSes?

Comment: This should be portable: `mkdir -p "$path" && cp -R somedir/* "$path"`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me because `somedir/*` is actually a path that looks like `/usr/local/bin/../share/foo/*`. For some reason with this path on OSX I get error `cp: /usr/local/bin/../share/foo/*: No such file or directory`. If I try with `/usr/local/share/foo/*` it works, but doesn't copy hidden files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (thanks @glenn jackman):

```
mkdir -p "$path"
cp -R "path/to/somedir/". "$path"
```

The only difference is that I've used `.` in place of `*`, to copy also hidden files.

This seems to work on both Ubuntu and OSX. Works also if `$path` is a dot.